# Is there a way to have a choropleth map in Excel reading data from a sheet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, excel, choropleth

Is it possible to have a solution similar to ESRI maps for office in which I want basically a geojson file or any file for that matters to render a choropleth map based on data in a sheet?

Tried already this tutorial http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2012/09/faster-choropleth-maps-with-microsoft-excel.html but I have a to do this in a way that can be dynamic. I was thinking exporting to geojson and loading on LeafletJS and be able to display it within Excel, is this even possible?

Comment: Found this extension for LibreOffice : http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/geooo but not sure how it works exactly... I've been wondering this myself, actually... will try this extension out sometime...

Comment: Seems to do something similar to what I need but it is based in LibreOffice and the client wants Excel, there must be something that doesn't involve convoluted transformation to freeforms hopefully. Nice extension and I will keep in mind for other projects

Comment: the client wants excel but they want to use GeoJSON? man who are these people???

Comment: Isn't the fun part? Trying to fulfill what they want? There must be some kind of solution I think, maybe just a VBA code that launches a browser with leafletjs. Already suggested other solutions but I think they are more comfortable with Excel for the data, probably because most people can open it and explore

Comment: can you embed an HTML frame in an excel sheet? (yes, that is the fun part...!)

Comment: Perhaps reveal.js might be of use? It's mapping capabilities are built on Leaflet, it can handle GeoJSON and it can take in .cvs files:
[http://okfnlabs.org/recline/docs/tutorial-backends.html](http://okfnlabs.org/recline/docs/tutorial-backends.html)